# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings fails to find settings

Tags: c#, web-config

With the following web.conig file located inside the project (in this case, a unit test project):

```
...
<appSettings>
  ...
  <add key ="SmtpPort" value="00"/>
  <add key="SmtpHost" value="site.site.com"/>
  <add key=""/>
</appSettings>
...
```

The following unit test fails:

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyAppSettingsAreRead()
{
    string port = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"];
    string host = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpHost"];

    Assert.IsTrue(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(port) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(host));
}
```

Further, System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys has exactly *one* key listed and it's not found in the web.config file at all. In fact searching the entire solution for the keys turns up nothing.

How do I correct the behavior of the WebConfigurationManager not returning the correct keys?

Comment: If it's inside test project, it probably shouldn't be called web.config. Rename it to app.config.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out an issue with an ASP.net project as reading from the web.config is having the exact same issue there, so ideally I'm reproducing it as closely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I see you reference the app.config and a web.config.

If you're trying to use web.config settings you should probably be using

[WebConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyAppSettingsAreRead()
{
    string port = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"];
    string host = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpHost"];

   Assert.IsTrue(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(port) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(host));
}
```

Comment: I tested it as you suggested (and edited my original post to adjust, as I imagine this is is required) but port and host still evaluate as null.